# PySpark - How to update TaskMetrics from Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, py4j

I have some data output source which can only be written to by a specific Python API. For that I am (ab)using foreachPartition(writing_func) from PySpark which works pretty well.
I wonder if its possible to somehow update the task metrics - specifically setBytesWritten - at the end of every partition. On the surface it seems impossible to me, for 2 reasons:

1. I don't think there is an open py4j gateway in a task context
2. TaskMetrics is accessed via ThreadLocal, so even with an open gateway it looks pretty tricky to get the right thread

Does anyone know of existing solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Accumulator.html) they are used to help report custom information into the spark UI/[REST API for metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/monitoring.html).  There is one caveat.  If a job is failed and retried then it will over report, but under the happy path they should be a good solution for you.

> ````
> a.value 7 sc.accumulator(1.0).value
> 1.0 sc.accumulator(1j).value 1j rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3]) def f(x):
>     global a
>     a += x rdd.foreach(f) a.value 13 b = sc.accumulator(0) def g(x):
>     b.add(x) rdd.foreach(g) b.value 6 ```
> ````

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for updating the TaskMetrics specifically :) I need the metrics to be attached to the task